# Ajax feed auto-refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got an auto-refresh snippet of code called News feed master and I have managed to implement and customize it to my own taste. Everything seems to be working except the auto-refresh which is meant to show my new post as I input it instead of having to refresh the whole page.

Here is a section of my index.php that queries the database for new feeds

```
<?php
/**
* Preparing and getting response for latest feed items.
**/
if(isset($_POST['latest_news_time'])){
$result = $db->query("SELECT *
FROM users U, messages M WHERE U.user_id = M.uid_fk AND M.created > '".$_POST['latest_news_time']."' ORDER BY M.created DESC");
$current_time = $_POST['latest_news_time'];
$item = $db->fetch_assoc($result);
$last_news_time = $item['created'];
while ($last_news_time < $current_time) {
    usleep(1000); //giving some rest to CPU
    $item = $db->fetch_assoc($result);
    $last_news_time = $item['created'];
}
?>
            <li id="<?=$item['created']?>">
            <div class="liSub">
                <div class="feed_image"><img src="uploads/user/<?=$item['image']?>" alt="<?=$item['image']?>"></div><!-- image -->
                <div class="head"><a href="profile.php?user=<?=$item['username']?>"><?=$item['first_name']?> <?=$item['last_name']?></a><?php if($item['status']=='politician')print"<img src='images/tick.png' alt='verified' class='verified'>";?></div><!-- username -->
                <div class="feedtext"><span><?=$item['message'];?></span></div><!-- message -->
                <div class="bottom">
                <p><?=$item['like_count']?></p><a href="#"><img src="images/Like-button.png" alt="like" class="like"></a><!-- like -->
                <p><?=$item['dislike_count']?></p><a href="#"><img src="images/disLike-button.png" alt="dislike" class="dislike"></a><!-- dislike -->
                <p><?=$item['comment_count']?> Comment(s)</p><!-- comments -->
                </div>
            </div>
            </li>
<?php
exit;
}
?>
```

And here's a section of my javascript that is supposed to perform the auto-refresh

```
/**
* Function to update the news feed
**/
function updateFeed(){
    var id = 0;
    id = $('#feeds li :first').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        'url' : 'index.php#feeds ul',
        'type' : 'POST',
        'data' : {
            'latest_news_time' : id  
        },
        success : function(data){
            setTimeout('updateFeed()', 1000);
            if(id != 0){
                $(data).prependTo("#feeds ul");
            }
        }
    }) 
}
```

I would be glad if you could help spot out the problem. I'm not a pro in jquery at all so it's giving me sleepless nights. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is an optional `cache` which the default value is true.  add this somewhere in your ajax call:

```
'cache': false,
```

Also, you may be getting a hidden error because you have no error handler:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

    alert(textStatus);

}
```

Comment: what values are passed in the function ?